# Rust Flatbuffers Index out of range error

Tags: rust, flatbuffers

I have a schema like this:

```
table BinaryValue {
    buf: [ubyte];
}

table MyValue {
    ...[some other fields]
    my_binary_value: BinaryValue;
}
```

When I try and access `my_binary_value` like this I get this message:

`'index 3136 out of range for slice of length 140'`

The code I use to access is:

```rust
        let my_binary_value = match op.my_binary_value() {
            Some(binary_value) => match binary_value.buf() {
                Some(buf) => {
                    println!(
                        "buf: {:?}",
                        buf
                    );
                    buf
                }
                None => {
                    return Err(format_err!("The my_binary_value is required."));
                }
            },
            None => {
                return Err(format_err!(
                    "The binary_value is required"
                ));
            }
        };
```

It panics on this line:

```
let my_binary_value = match op.my_binary_value() {
```

I printed out the value of binary_value and it looks OK (truncated):

```
Some(BinaryValue { _tab: Table { buf: [20, 0, 0, 0, 48, 52, ...], loc: 60 } })
```

Here is the generated flatbuffer code:

```
#[inline]
  pub fn buf(&self) -> Option<&'a [u8]> {
    self._tab.get::<flatbuffers::ForwardsUOffset<flatbuffers::Vector<'a, u8>>>(BinaryValue::VT_BUF, None).map(|v| v.safe_slice())
  }
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I voted to close your question as "unclear", because frankly, there is literally too little to go by to make any suggestion; we don't even know what the buffer you started with is, so how could we help in debugging a mismatched length/out of bounds error? Consider refining your question and your code further.

Comment: I will try and be more complete next time. I did find it, I had a `union` and I mistakenly had the wrong type in the `..._type` field.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this, see the comment above. It is important to be sure with a union field to put the proper type in the `..._type` field, as that cannot be type-checked.